# Ways to use h() render function in Vue

Tags: vue.js

```
<template v-for="thing in things" :key="word">
    <renderfunc :thing="thing" />
</template>

<script setup>
const renderfunc = (thing:any) => {
    return h('span', 
                   { 
                     onmouseenter : () => doSomething }
                     //...more stuff
                    }, 
            thing.thing)
}


</script>
```

**Reason for using h(): **
add event listeners to html element, like onmouseenter, programmatically, because they can be changed by the user.

This setup is working, but it this the correct way and reason to be using render/h()?

It there a better way of using h() to insert elements into the <template>?

Many thanks.

This is working correctly, but I don't know if this is the correct way to use h()